# user is not authorized to assume IAM Role

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift, aws-cloudformation

I have a bash script which pulls information from a CloudFormation stack and places it into a Python script. The Python script is intended to connect to a Redshift database, create a table, then import data from a file downloaded from an S3 bucket.

The first part works:

```
endpoint=$(aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name=BallotOnlineRS --region=us-west-2 \
            --query 'Stacks[0].Outputs[?OutputKey==`RedshiftClusterEndpointAddress`].OutputValue' \
            --output text)

role=$(aws cloudformation describe-stack-resources --stack-name=BallotOnlineRS --region=us-west-2 \
            --logical-resource-id RawDataBucketAccessRole |grep 'PhysicalResourceId' |cut -d: -f2 |sed 's/^ //; s/,//; s/"//g')

sed -i "s/ENDPOINT/${endpoint}/; s/ROLE/${role}/" /tmp/ballotonline_data.py
```

This results in the the necessary strings going where they need to:

```
HOST = 'ballotonliners-redshiftcluster-xxxxxxxxxxxx.cgsdneukfjtv.us-west-2.redshift.amazonaws.com'

ARN_CREDENTIALS = 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:role/BallotOnlineRS-RawDataBucketAccessRole-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

However, when I execute the Python script, I get the following error from `sqlalchemy`:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (psycopg2.errors.InternalError_) User arn:aws:redshift:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxx:dbuser:ballotonliners-redshiftcluster-1qb2hxkta10t9/admin is not authorized to assume IAM Role arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:role/BallotOnlineRS-RawDataBucketAccessRole-1U56NHFY528VW
DETAIL:
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  User arn:aws:redshift:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxx:dbuser:ballotonliners-redshiftcluster-xxxxxxxxxxxx/admin is not authorized to assume IAM Role arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:role/BallotOnlineRS-RawDataBucketAccessRole-xxxxxxxxxxxx
  code:      8001
  context:   IAM Role=arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:role/BallotOnlineRS-RawDataBucketAccessRole-xxxxxxxxxxxx
  query:     76
  location:  xen_aws_credentials_mgr.cpp:272
  process:   padbmaster [pid=13823]
  -----------------------------------------------
```

The `admin` user mentioned in the error is created when the Redshift stack is created and if I access the database through the Redshift UI by logging into the Query Editor, I get no error using the same account. The difference in that situation is that I'm logging in with the username:password rather than, I'm guessing, assuming a role. Specifically, the one in the error.

The Redshift stack is built using a template [provided by Thorntech](https://s3.amazonaws.com/thorntech-public-documents/cf-templates/redshift.yml). This also is successful when executed.

Any thoughts on what the issue is?

**EDIT:**
I found what should be an identical issue on the [AWS Developer forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=759810) that indicates that rather than using the physical resource ID, I should be using the logical ID. In this case, instead of `BallotOnlineRS-RawDataBucketAccessRole-xxxxxxxxxxxx` I should just use `RawDataBucketAccessRole`. However, that results in the same error with difference being that the logical ID replaces the physical ID.

**EDIT2:**
In response to John Rotenstein's question regarding associating the role, here is the section that defines the cluster and its relevant components:

```
Resources:
  RedshiftCluster: 
    Type: AWS::Redshift::Cluster
    Properties: 
      ClusterSubnetGroupName: !Ref RedshiftClusterSubnetGroup
      ClusterType: !If [ SingleNode, single-node, multi-node ]  
      NumberOfNodes: !If [ SingleNode, !Ref 'AWS::NoValue', !Ref RedshiftNodeCount ] #'
      DBName: !Sub ${DatabaseName}
      IamRoles:
        - !GetAtt RawDataBucketAccessRole.Arn
      MasterUserPassword: !Ref MasterUserPassword
      MasterUsername: !Ref MasterUsername
      PubliclyAccessible: true
      NodeType: dc2.large
      Port: 5439
      VpcSecurityGroupIds: 
        - !Sub ${RedshiftSecurityGroup}
      PreferredMaintenanceWindow: Sun:09:15-Sun:09:45
  DataBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Sub ${DataBucketName}
  RawDataBucketAccessRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement: 
          - 
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - redshift.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
  RawDataBucketRolePolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: RawDataBucketRolePolicy
      PolicyDocument: 
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - 
            Effect: Allow
            Action: s3:ListAllMyBuckets
            Resource: arn:aws:s3:::*
          - 
            Effect: Allow
            Action: 
              - 's3:Get*'
              - 's3:List*'
            Resource: '*'
          - 
            Effect: Allow
            Action: cloudwatch:*
            Resource: "*"
      Roles:
        - !Ref RawDataBucketAccessRole
```

Does it matter that the cluster is defined prior to the role? I suspect it doesn't since the role is listed under the stack's Resources tab in the CF UI.

**EDIT3:**
I found another, [similar issue](https://discourse.snowplowanalytics.com/t/data-loading-error-to-redshift/1559) but for a product. The OP states that he found the solution. Being that he was using the wrong role to authenticate with. When I looked into that avenue for my issue, it does not appear to apply since I only have the one role.

Comment: Did you (or the CloudFormation template) associate the Role with the Redshift cluster? It would be done via an `IamRoles` parameter in the `AWS::Redshift::Cluster` properties of the CloudFormation template.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I added the relevant CF snippet to the body of the question.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Short answer, yes, the `IamRoles` parameter is being associated with the cluster.

Comment: I'm a little confused about where your `admin` user is defined. Is it the `MasterUsername` from the CloudFormation template, or are you using another method for authentication?

Comment: Yes, `MasterUsername` is a parameter in the template. It defaults to admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reached a point where I was throwing things at the wall to see what would stick. Eventually I got it to work. What I don't know is, which of the final two changes that I made at one time solved the problem (or why): adding the `Path:` property to the `IAM::Role` definition or placing the policy inline with the role definition and removing the external policy definition. What I ended up with is (compare this to what I've placed in the body of the question above)

```
  RawDataBucketAccessRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - 
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - 'redshift.amazonaws.com'
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: '/'
      RoleName: RawDataBucketAccessRole
      Policies:
        - 
          PolicyName: RawDataBucketRolePolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - 
                Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 's3:Get*'
                  - 's3:List*'
                Resource: '*'
```

This allows the `admin` user (defined in the `MasterUsername` parameter) to assume the role and access the S3 bucket.